# TRANSFORM clause in ML models : are preprocessing steps done after data splitting?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I create a ML model with a TRANSFORM clause containing one or several pre-processing steps, it seems to me that those steps are not visible in the temporary training and evaluation data tables which can be accessed from the `Details` tab after model creation.
For instance, in this tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-transform):

```
#standardSQL
CREATE MODEL `bqml_tutorial.natality_model`
TRANSFORM(weight_pounds,
    is_male,
    gestation_weeks,
    ML.QUANTILE_BUCKETIZE(mother_age,
      5) OVER() AS bucketized_mother_age,
    CAST(mother_race AS string) AS mother_race,
    ML.FEATURE_CROSS(STRUCT(is_male,
        CAST(mother_race AS STRING) AS mother_race)) is_male_mother_race)
OPTIONS
  (model_type='linear_reg',
    input_label_cols=['weight_pounds']) AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
WHERE
  weight_pounds IS NOT NULL
  AND RAND() < 0.001
```

the new feature `bucketized_mother_age` would neither appear in the temporary training and evaluation data tables nor in the ML.FEATURE_INFO() table.
Is it indeed the expected behavior? Is there a way to access transformed features?

Also, if in the example above, `mother_age` has Null values, is automatic imputation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/auto-preprocessing#imputation) done before bucketization?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Please see the replies below:

1. Yes, the preprocessing is done after data split, because it is based on the statistics/dictionary of the training split. (similar to other frameworks). Therefore, it's expected to not see the new columns in the split tables or ML.FEATURE_INFO.
2. Yes, we are about to launch a new TVF that enables customers to see the transformed data. Feel free to join the upcoming BQML user forum for demos.
3. The automatic preprocessing (e.g., auto imputation) is done after the TRANSFORM clause. You can use ML.IMPUTE inside the TRANSFORM clause to get it done first.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian for your clear answer. This is very helpful!